A gtk shortcuts window from which the object is retrieved from gtk_builder_get_object() can only be shown once
In Gtk version 4 I have described a shortcuts window in XML which is read by GtkBuilder successfully. I then get the object from the builder with gtk_builder_get_object() after which it is shown; image of a shortcuts window. This works ok. When I'm done looking at it, I press the cross button at the top right and the window disappears. When I want to show it a second time, I get the message
(puzzle-table:113650): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:01:14.576: A window is shown after it has been destroyed. This will leave the window in an inconsistent state.

I have tried several things like increasing the reference count etc, but I think that, when closing the window, the object gets destroyed whatever the state of the reference is and the builder can not give a proper shortcut window object anymore.
Is it possible to clone that object and use that instead?
Is there another way to keep the object alive in the builder?
Studying the Gtk demo program I see that the builder is instantiated each time it is needed. Seems a bit of a waste to have to reload the UI files all the time.
